# Laravel in primary, wordpress in subdomain, how to setup

Tags: laravel, wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I have the domain e.g:

maindomain.com
with an installation of laravel and .htaccess file as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also have an installation of wordpress 5.8.1 in the subdomain:
portal.maindomain.com
with currently "empty" .htaccess file as:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

I have also tried in subdomain .htaccess as:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and even :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /portal/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /portal/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

with no luck.
Subdomain always produce:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

the wordpress domain in wp_options table in database is defined as:

```
https://portal.maindomain.com
```

Any ideas on how to set .htaccess files for both installations to work?

Comment: Where do these subdomains and main domain point to on the filesystem in relation to each other?

Comment: Currently the main domain (laravel) use the first .htaccess configuration of my post and the subdomain (wordpress) the second  .htaccess configuration. Nothing else has been configured in cpanel regarding redirections etc...

Comment: The question was what is the directory structure, and where are the docroots of each domain.  Eg maindomain.com docroot is `/var/www/maindomain.com/public` maybe?  And where is the WP site?  Can you put it at  `/var/www/portal.maindomain.com`?